# Using composer to manage premium WordPress plugins

Tags: wordpress, composer-php

I am using composer to handle my WordPress installation, in particular I am setting up my premium plugins as private repos with my own 'composer.json' file that looks like this....

```
{
    "name": "privateplugin/myplugin",
    "description": "Private repo for premium plugin",
    "type": "wordpress-plugin",
    "require": {
      "composer/installers": "^1.0"
    },
}
```

This has been working great so far, but now I have a premium plugin that already has a `composer.json` file in it's root. This obviously conflicts with the `composer.json` file that I am creating.

How can I overcome this issue?